# Use I18n in url

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i have this url in tempalte but it doesn't works:

```html
    <a :href="`/${i18n.locale}'/profiles/'${teammate.profile.id}`" target="_blank">Hi</a>
```

my i18n file

```js
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
    
    Vue.use(VueI18n)
    
    let index = {}
    index[window.I18n_locale] = window.I18n
    
    // Ready translated locale messages
    const messages = index
    
    // Create VueI18n instance with options
    export default new VueI18n({
        locale: window.I18n_locale, // set locale
        messages, // set locale messages
    })
```

gives me this error in console:

> Property or method "i18n" is not defined on the instance but
> referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive,
> either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
> initializing the property.

how should i write it to make it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable name should be `$i18n`.

```html
<a :href="`/${$i18n.locale}/profiles/${teammate.profile.id}`" target="_blank">Hi</a>
```

From the [Vue18n documentation](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/locale.html):

> Each component contains a VueI18n instance referenced as the $i18n property...